# NPM Datatable Excel button not showing

Tags: jquery, node.js, excel, datatable, datatables

My **Excel** Button in datatable is now showing up. I'm using NPM to import all scripts,  **all others buttons works well** (*PDF, Copy, Print*). Only **Excel** do not work.

**Check my imports**:

```
import 'datatables.net-bs'
import 'datatables.net-buttons-bs'
import 'datatables.net-responsive-bs'
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js'
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js'
import 'jszip'
import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake'
import pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts'
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js'
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js'

pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs
```

**My config**:

```
let datatableConfig = {
    responsive: true,
    "dom": '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgtip',
    "buttons": [
        { extend: 'copy' },
        { extend: 'excel'}, 
        { extend: 'excelHtml5' },
        { extend: 'pdf'  },
        { extend: 'print' }
    ]
};

$('#dataTable').DataTable(datatableConfig)
```

> If i put `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.4/jszip.min.js` direct in my HTML, it works. How it do not work using `import`? *(Yes, jszip is already installed)*

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I got the same issue with the `require` syntax and I had to do :

```
window.JSZip = require( "jszip" );
```

I don't know the syntax with `import` but maybe it's something like

```
import window.JSZip from 'jszip';
```

or

```
JSZip from 'jszip';
```

or

```
import JSZip from 'jszip';
window.JSZip = JSZip;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Apparently we just need to expose `window.JSZip`. Thanks again, it solved to me.

Answer (score 2):

If someone doesn't want to expose `jszip`, now in DataTables is possible to add that library directly to Buttons:

```js
// import section
import $ from 'jquery';
import jszip from 'jszip';
import pdfmake from 'pdfmake';
import 'datatables.net';
import 'datatables.net-buttons';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5';

// add pdfmake or jszip directly to DT Buttons
$.fn.dataTable.Buttons.jszip(jszip);
$.fn.dataTable.Buttons.pdfMake(pdfmake);
```

[Source](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/139488/#Comment_139488)