# excelHtml5 button not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vuejs2, datatables-1.10

I'm using the latest DataTables-bs4 and buttons-bs4 version (1.10.19 and 1.5.4 respectively) in a Laravel-Vue project and the export to excel button is not showing up, CSV and PDF are working as intended

This is how I'm importing all the necessary dependencies in the bootstrap.js file:

```
import jszip from 'jszip';
import datatable_responsive_bs4 from 'datatables.net-responsive-bs4';
import datatable_buttons_bs4 from 'datatables.net-buttons-bs4';
import datatable_buttons_html5 from 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5';
/*
* other code over here
*
*
*/
window.jszip = jszip;
window.datatable_responsive_bs4 = datatable_responsive_bs4;
window.datatable_buttons_bs4 = datatable_buttons_bs4;
window.datatable_buttons_html5 = datatable_buttons_html5;
window.pdfmake = require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js');
window.vfs_fonts = require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js');
window.pdfmake.vfs = window.vfs_fonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

And this is how I'm initializing the DataTable:

```
$('#table').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    responsive: true,
    buttons: [
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            orientation: 'landscape',
            pageSize: 'LEGAL'
        }
    ],
    order: [[1, 'desc']]
});
```

This is the most I can get, excel is not showing up at all:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and what can I change to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution based on this one: [NPM Datatable Excel button not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829916/npm-datatable-excel-button-not-showing?rq=1)

it was changing this:

```
import jszip from 'jszip';
//
window.jszip = jszip;
```

to this:

```
import JSZip from 'jszip';
//
window.JSZip = JSZip;
```

For some reason the library needs this exact variable name to be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
   extend: 'excelHtml5',
   autoFilter: true,
   sheetName: 'Exported data'
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this didn't fix it